# Apache2 with xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, html, apache, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I have a JavaScript function where I pass a path/name of a server-side directory in-order to return the paths/names of sub-directories to an array. ***Additional console.log()s were added in-order to check the flow.***

*Below function was sourced from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133213/14489697) and then tweaked a bit to match the need.*

```js
function loadSubDir(dir) {
  console.log("Initial method call with ", dir);
  let res = null;
  let path = null;
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", dir, false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    res = xmlhttp.response;
    $(res)
      .find(" td > a ")
      .each(function() {
        path = $(this).attr("href");
        console.log("Values for Categories : ", path);
        subDirs.push(path);
      });
  }
  subDirs.shift();
  return subDirs;
}
```

This works fine without any issue in my local Apache server where I use the default Apache configuration with only adding document root for the directory where this JavaScript file is available.

But if I use the same implementation on another Apache server environment, this **FAILS**. Having put logs, I noticed that "Values for Categories" log does not appear when running on server.

Is there any additional configurations needed or what could be the reason ?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `xmlhttp.status`? What is `res`? What does the Network tab show? Is the request successful with the data you expect? Look at the request and response headers. Anything unexpected there? Do they match what you see in your working test environment?

Comment: Saying that "it fails" is nowhere near informative enough to answer your question. What xmlhttp.status do you get when it fails? What is shown in the browser console under the Network tab?

Comment: Dear @Quentin thanks for taking your time and attention for the question. `res` was used as in `result`. So when I was checking I got to know we were using Apache on docker and configured that in my PC as well and I noticed the differences in responses as you mentioned. So I changed what parameters I passed into **_.find()_** method. **.find("li > a")** instead of **.find("td > a")**.. Then it continued the execution.. Thank you for the suggestion..

Comment: Dear @ocrdu thanks for time and attention given for this question. I hope I did managed to explain what I did to solve the issue I had in the comment above. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how I have implemented $(res).find() method. In my local Apache server environment, the response was;

```
<html>
 <head><title>Index of /XXXX-XXX</title></head>
 <body>
  <h1>Index of /XXXX-XXX</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-14 17:10  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-15 11:25  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-15 11:25  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-14 18:00  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-14 17:53  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-15 11:24  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-14 17:53  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></td><td align="right">2020-12-14 17:54  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr></table><address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)Server at localhost Port 80</address>
 </body>
</html>
```

So.. ***$(res).find(" td > a ")*** works..
Since we were using Apache o docker, the response was;

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /XXXX-XXX</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Index of /XXXX-XXX</h1>
  <ul><li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  <li><a href="XXX/">XXX/</a></li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

here, instead of ***$(res).find("td > a")*** I needed to use the .find() method as ***$(res).find("li > a")***.

Then it continued the execution.