# Reading a html page, replacing in a custom tag and outputting (cgi). Is this a good idea?

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am making (my first) webpage. I installed apache2, and in order to have dynamic content, am using cgi: i thought of making a python script that reads a html page, which has a custom tag and then the python script edits things in that tag in order to have dynamic content in the page. Is this a good or bad way to accomplish this?

The python script would be something like this:

```
page = open("page.html", "r").read()
# some code to replace things inside the custom tag <custom-tag>
print(page)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a “custom Tag” and how you want the page to be edited? If I was you, I would just use PHP or JS to provide dynamic content.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang just somewhere in the html page will be `<custom-tag></custom-tag>` so the python program finds that place and edits there.

Comment: Under what circumstances would that be necessary?

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang i wish the page to communicate with another program in my computer, and have content in it depending on current data. For example i could have a text file with some information which the python file would also read and replace it in the page so that when the webpage is accessed this information appears on page.

Comment: As I said, I would just use JavaScript and maybe SQL as your database.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang i thought javascript couldn't provide dynamic content since it cannot access server-side files

Comment: It is possible to access server-side files using `XMLHttpRequest` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921947).